# Add more data into cookie in PHP

Tags: php, cookies

I have a cookie and I'm storing multiple checked checkbox values of page1 in this. Now I want to add more checked checkbox values into the cookie of page2 and then page3 and so on (I'm using pagination in my code). How can I do that in PHP?

```
<?php
$cookiename = "emp";
if (isset($_GET['check_list']) ) {
    setcookie($cookiename , implode(',' , $_GET['check_list']) , 
time()+(86400/86400*30) );
}
?>
//to print the values
<?php
if (isset($_COOKIE[$cookiename]) ) {
    print_r($_COOKIE);
}
?>
```

Comment: Well you are storing a comma-separated list of values … So concatenate the new values you are storing with the current content of the cookie …?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe in this way:

```
<?php

$page = $_GET['page'];
$cookiename = "emp";
// GET COOKIE TO NOT OVERWRITE.
$cookie = isset($_COOKIE[$cookiename]) ? unserialize($_COOKIE[$cookiename]) : [];

if (isset($_GET['check_list']) ) {
    $cookie[$page] = $_GET['check_list'];
    setcookie($cookiename , serialize($cookie), time()+(86400/86400*30) );
}
?>

//to print the values
<?php
if (isset($_COOKIE[$cookiename]) ) {
    print_r(unserialize($_COOKIE[$cookiename]));
}
?>
```

With [unserialize](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.unserialize.php) you can store a multiple dimension array into a cookie with no problem.